# jquery preventDefault() ведёт себя некорректно

Tags: jquery

Есть меню, которое имеет 2 версии. десктоп и мобильную. Я хочу запретить переход по ссылкам первого уровня в мобильной версии меню. Делаю следующее:

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.nav.open a.parent', function(event) {       
      event.preventDefault();   //Блокируем переход по родительскому пункту
      console.log('Блокируем ссылку');
      $(this).parent().siblings('li').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('open');
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');       
     // return false;
  });
```

где сочетание классов .nav.open появляется только при нажатии на кнопку показа меню в мобильной версии сайта. Код отрабатывает со второго раза, т.е. если первый раз зайти на сайт, включить эмуляцию мобильного телефона (вид вёрстки изменится), открыть меню и перейти по ссылке первого уровня - произойдёт переход с перегрузом страницы. Если тут же повторить операцию - отработает event.preventDefault();.

Я поставил вывод в консоль элемента $('.nav.open a.parent'), он как раз появляется при нажатии на кнопку показа меню http://joxi.ru/DmBXGOZhNLP0oA .

В чём может быть проблема? Почему  event.preventDefault(); не отрабатывает с первого раза?

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавить [минимальный воспроизводимый код проблемы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Так сходу проблем в JS-коде (не считая отсутствия кэширования `$(this).parent()` и непонятно зачем используемого `.not($(this).parent())`) не видно

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.nav a.parent', function(event) { 
     var parent = $(this).parent(); 
     if (parent.hasClass('open')) {
         event.preventDefault();   //Блокируем переход по родительскому пункту
          console.log('Блокируем ссылку');
     }   
      
     parent.siblings('li').not(parent).removeClass('open');
     parent.toggleClass('open');       
    // return false;
  });
```

Попробуйте так. должно работать. но правильней и логичней обработчик вешать не сразу, а тогда когда он нужен